# Should I declare as Queue or PriorityQueue when I want to use PriorityQueue in Java?

Tags: java, interface, queue, priority-queue

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(); // first

Queue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();  // second
```

My Question:

Which one is better? I see many examples use first one, however I also heard [program against interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming). The type of declaration should be **as general as possible**. PriorityQueue implements Queue interface, therefore from second argument, we should use second one.

PS:
This example is quite different from `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()` vs
`List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()`, since I never see any production codes use the first one for `ArrayList` and we always use the second one. However, I really see many examples use the first one for `PriorityQueue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an interface general enough to fit your needs and not impose implementation details, but specific enough to fit your exact use case.

If you need some queue without any use of prioritization functionality (e.g. your code does not use any knowledge of prioritization), then use `Queue`. That way you can change actual implementation within single line.

If your code uses prioritization features and rely on them, then you definitely should use `PriorityQueue`, because `Queue` will be too general and will lead to errors when prioritization methods are called.